# How to enable Apps For Websites API for uwp apps deployed via the Microsoft Store?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'm adding this API to my app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking. This API allows websites to open UWP apps instead when the user clicks on a link from another app. In debug mode, this all works correctly (clicking on a specific link while in Skype app will open my app instead of opening the browser). However, this does NOT work when I deployed my app to the store (clicking on the same link would open the browser).

My app is open source and I've added all the proper configurations in the package manifest: https://github.com/jenius-apps/ambie/blob/430acf4395585343e6474d7de26826471aac5a08/src/AmbientSounds.Uwp/Package.appxmanifest#L52-L56
[image]

Here you can see the my app is properly configured in Windows Settings as the app for my specific website:
[image]

But as I said earlier, when I click on this link in Skype or some other local app, the browser opens instead of the app: https://ambie-app.azurewebsites.net/play?sounds=KxXf4GZxKkCQLcadOp-Wuw,B2baqr5d_0KTTdWRfllyhA.

Why is this working correctly in debug mode but not in release mode?

Comment: Could you please tell me whether you have checked the app Package Family Name inside JSON file that defines the association between your app and your website? Is it the same as the app manifest declaration after you associated your app to the store?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Yes, I checked. Here is the package family name for my app according to Partner Center: 43891JeniusApps.Ambie_jaj7tphbgjeh8. And here's the JSON file from my website: https://ambie-app.azurewebsites.net/windows-app-web-link. You can see the package family name in that JSON is the same.

Comment: After you associate your project with the partner center, Have you tried to run the release build in your device or create a sideload package and install it on your device to test? Do you still get the same issue?

Comment: Hi, May I know the solution here. I did the exact same and I posted the web URL on teams chat. when I click the teams chat link my app opens. But when I click the same link embedded on a web page the Url opens in the browser rather than opening the app.

Comment: @YanGu Also, I would like to know if I accidentally checked the "Always use" how to reset it. Please see the link. https://csharpdotchristiannageldotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/deeplinkingopen.png?w=672